# Ionic - SCSS - '[scss] ) expected' && '[scss] { expected' error messages

Tags: sass, ionic2

I am fairly new to Ionic and I'm using the ionic 2 beta using angular 2. Now this works with Sass. And ionic generates their default styling in your application `app/theme/app.variables.css` where the `primary`and `secondary` etc. colors are defined. The default scss file they give you looks like this:

```
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/

// Ionic Shared Functions
// --------------------------------------------------
// Makes Ionic Sass functions available to your App

@import "globals.core";

// App Shared Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// To customize the look and feel of this app, you can override
// the Sass variables found in Ionic's source scss files. Setting
// variables before Ionic's Sass will use these variables rather than
// Ionic's default Sass variable values. App Shared Sass imports belong
// in the app.core.scss file and not this file. Sass variables specific
// to the mode belong in either the app.ios.scss or app.md.scss files.


// App Shared Color Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// It's highly recommended to change the default colors
// to match your app's branding. Ionic uses a Sass map of
// colors so you can add, rename and remove colors as needed.
// The "primary" color is the only required color in the map.
// Both iOS and MD colors can be further customized if colors
// are different per mode.

$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  favorite:   #69BB7B
);
```

And, as provided in their docs, this is the correct code. (although they don't include `favorite`).

[image: My Code] [image: Docs]

**btw the extra comma on the end of dark doesn't change anything**

Now the problem is that I get 2 errors. 1 on the `primary:    #387ef5,` at the colon. Saying `[scss] ) expected.`

[image: primary error message]

And 1 on the `secondary:  #32db64,` on the colon saying `[scss] { expected.`
[image]

Comment: it is the full error message

Comment: there's none showing in the browser but this is the one in the editor. also changing my html having 1 directive like danger and changing this color variable doesn't change anything

Comment: And when I remove primary and secondary it will still give the same error message but on the next 2 lines

Comment: according to the ionic docs, and their youtube tutorial (ionic 1), you can customise their default color styles. The colors in this `$colors:` can be used as directives so `<p danger>` to give it that color. Primary is used for buttons etc. I want to change that color

Comment: I got this error little back but when i tried to create new project, it got resolved. Try to start an ionic template again and check. May solve the issue.

Comment: @Aish123 I tried recreating this sidemenu template, still got the error. Also tried creating both tabs layout and blank layout. scss files stay the same in all those templates, got an error on all :/

Answer (score 0):

simply do this:

```
$colors: (
  'primary':    #387ef5,
  'secondary':  #32db64,
  'danger':     #f53d3d,
  'light':      #f4f4f4,
  'dark':       #222,
  'favorite':   #69BB7B
);
```

Comment: Still getting the same errors, secondary is now entire underlined instead of just the colon.

Comment: its working fine on my end :O, which version of sass are you using? this feature is available starting from 3.3+

Comment: i'm not experienced with sass, just generated this project through ionic, so I wouldn't really know where to look. But I found a package.json file which shows some version numbers. It says `gulp-sass@^2.2.0` so i guess 2.2?

Comment: Gulp is version 3.9.1

Comment: @ivaro18 you have to check for node-sass in the deps

Comment: the `package.json` file shows me 3 things, `"raw" : "node-sass@^3.4.2"` , `"_id": "node-sass@3.8.0"` and `"_nodeVersion": "5.10.1"`