# SCSS Syntax Error When Using Include-media

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am using [include-media](https://include-media.com/) in a project and getting the syntax error

> [scss] ) expected

when viewing this mixin in my vscode editor. I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271141/ionic-scss-scss-expected-scss-expected-error-messages) question, but it is not about the same syntax I am experiencing.

Here is a screenshot of the section with a problem in [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eduardoboucas/include-media/master/dist/_include-media.scss) file

[image]

*I have not made not made any changes to this mixin, I simply downloaded and included it in the project it as outlined [here](https://include-media.com/#download)*

**Questions**:

1. What is causing this error?
2. How come I am still able to use this mixin even though it has an error?
3. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**1. What is causing this error?**
This issue is occuring because vscode editor does not support css preprocessors completely.

**2. How come I am still able to use this mixin even though it has an error?**
You will get your output as the include-media scss is completely fine.

**3. How can I solve this?**
You need to add vscode service for css which will help to detect css pre-processors syntax and your error will be resolved. Include this vscode script in your vscode editor. As mention here.

```
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice
```

Thanks